# Salesforce Deployment-Users, Profiles and security settings

Tags: deployment

I primarily use sandbox for the development. A question popped up yesterday, should we use same approach for Users, Profiles and security settings. I meant creating them first in sandbox and migrating them via ChangeSets. I never did this but I read somewhere It is better to configure Users, Profiles and security settings directly in production Org. Just wanted to know your thoughts on this. Would appreciate your feedback.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The Admin who handles sandbox and Production needs to follow any one approach.

- Do User, Profile, Security Setting directly in production if you start this approach, always needs to follow this approach.
- Do changes in sandbox and then migrate to Production.

Problem come in such situation where you do changes in production and then you go second approach where you do change in sandbox and then production. then previous changes in production will be overridden.